# Having a problem with bridges at boot on ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: networking, server, 18.04

I'm having a problem with bridges in ubuntu server 18.04. This machine has two NICs in it, and I'm binding the bridge to one of them, and attaching containers to the bridge. I'm setting up services for the lan on the containers, and using static IPs via the bridge to make them available to the subnet. However, when I boot the system I don't end up getting an IP address on the bridge:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::7e8b:caff:fe03:57b0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 7c:8b:ca:03:57:b0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 167  bytes 19385 (19.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 50  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 36  bytes 2946 (2.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::7e8b:caff:fe03:57b0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 7c:8b:ca:03:57:b0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 758  bytes 637232 (637.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 433  bytes 33998 (33.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 30:9c:23:41:a4:1b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 64  bytes 5104 (5.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 64  bytes 5104 (5.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethCHVFR2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fcf7:29ff:fe05:734b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:f7:29:05:73:4b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 348  bytes 26797 (26.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 422  bytes 350547 (350.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethLPOSTU: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fcb3:33ff:fe5b:4bbb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:b3:33:5b:4b:bb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 49  bytes 4363 (4.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 172  bytes 279551 (279.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces file on the global host:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


# The primary network interface
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet manual

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet manual
#  address 192.168.5.19
#  netmask 255.255.255.0
#  gateway 192.168.5.1
#  dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
#


auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        bridge_ports enp2s0
        address 192.168.5.20
#        network 192.168.5.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.5.255
        gateway 192.168.5.1
#        bridge_fd 9
#        bridge_hello 2
#        bridge_maxage 12
        bridge_stp off
        dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
        dns-search XXX.network
```

The thing is, when I issue a "service networking restart" I end up having all the stuff come together the way it's supposed to:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.5.20  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.5.255
        inet6 fe80::7e8b:caff:fe03:57b0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 7c:8b:ca:03:57:b0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 122  bytes 12409 (12.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 21  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 91  bytes 8072 (8.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 7c:8b:ca:03:57:b0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 914  bytes 654161 (654.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 522  bytes 41870 (41.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 30:9c:23:41:a4:1b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 64  bytes 5104 (5.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 64  bytes 5104 (5.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethCHVFR2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fcf7:29ff:fe05:734b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:f7:29:05:73:4b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 350  bytes 26933 (26.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 430  bytes 351218 (351.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethLPOSTU: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fcb3:33ff:fe5b:4bbb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:b3:33:5b:4b:bb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 54  bytes 4625 (4.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 180  bytes 280218 (280.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and everything starts working as it should. Any ideas about where I should look so that the network starts properly instead of needing to be repunted in order for the configuration to take?

Thanks!

Comment: In Ubuntu server 17.10 and later, networking is handled by *netplan* by default. I am not, however, experienced in bridges.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. I've done a little reading on it. There are no yaml files floating around, but this is a system I upgraded from 16.04. This is still a WIP system, so I may go for installing from scratch after backing it up so I can compare how they work.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be the interaction between ifupdown and netplan. After I configured netplan, the system came up as it should. I suspect the issue was a timing one during startup where it was unable to assign an address to the bridge because key parts of the networking subsystem weren't up yet. I purged ifupdown and configured netplan and everything started working.

Thank you @chili555 for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: [Ubuntu Bionic: Netplan blog post](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/12/01/ubuntu-bionic-netplan)